Understanding the transpose of a (generalized) Calderon-Zygmund operator
I have been reading Fourier Analysis by Javier Duoandikoetxea, and I have a question about generalized Calderon-Zygmund operators. For reference, I state the definition as given in the book.

Definition (Generalized Calderon-Zygmund Operators): An operator $T$ is a generalized Calderon-Zygmund operator if T is bounded on $L^2 ( \mathbb{R}^n )$, and there is a standard kernel $K$ such that for any $f \in L^2 ( \mathbb{R}^n )$ with compact support, we have
$$Tf ( x ) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} K (x, y) f (y) \mathrm{d}y,$$
for $x \notin \text{supp} (f)$

Here, by a standard kernel, we mean a function $K: ( \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n ) \setminus \Delta \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, that satisfies for some $\delta > 0$ and all $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}^n$
$$\left| K (x, y) \right| \leq \frac{C}{\left| x - y \right|^{n}},$$
$$\left| K \left( x, y \right) - K \left( x, z \right) \right| \leq C \frac{\left| y - z \right|^{\delta}}{\left| x - y \right|^{n + \delta}}, \text{ whenever } \left| x - y \right| > 2 \left| y - z \right|,$$
$$\left| K \left( x, y \right) - K \left( w, y \right) \right| \leq C \frac{\left| x - w \right|^{\delta}}{\left| x - y \right|^{n + \delta}}, \text{ whenever } \left| x - y \right| > 2 \left| x - w \right|.$$
Often, in the proofs of the $L^p$-boundedness of such operators, the authors have used a duality argument. However, to do so, we require to understand the transpose of $T$. In fact, what I believe (and is used in the text) is that the transpose $T^t$ is also a Calderon-Zygmund operator with the kernel $\tilde{K} (x, y) = K (y, x)$. Indeed, it is easy to argue that $T^t$ is bounded on $L^2 (\mathbb{R}^n)$. However, I am not able to prove that for compactly supported functions $f$, we have
$$T^tf (x) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} K (y, x) f(y) \mathrm{d}y.$$
I tried starting with the integral
$$\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} Tf(x) g(x) \mathrm{d}x = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) T^tg(x) \mathrm{d}x.$$
On the left hand side, we have
$$\int\limits_{\text{supp}(g)} Tf(x) g(x) \mathrm{d}x.$$
However, I am unable to proceed beyond this, since we have to comment upon the expression of $T^tg$ on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \text{supp}(g)$.
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated!
